For a normed vector space, does there exists minimal dense subspace(s)?
Given a normed vector space $V$, does there always exist some proper dense subspace which contains no other dense subspace except itself? If this is the case, is there any nontrivial properties for these space?
For finite dimension, it is impossible to have proper subspace with this property. For a infinite dimensional space, it seems to be possible. For a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_{n})$, the set $span(e_{n}:n\geq1)$ is dense, and removing any $e_{i}$ from it will make the set not dense.

Removing any $e_n$ will make the span not dense, true, but the span of $e_n$ is not minimal - by Gram-Schmidt procedure, any countably-infinite dimensional inner product space is isomorphic to $\text{span}(e_n)$, so if you choose some $x \in \ell^2 \setminus \text{span}(e_n)$, then the span of $x$ together with $e_n$ is isomorphic to the span of $e_n$, but clearly the span of $e_n$ is dense in the span of $e_n$ and $x$, so by the isomorphism above the span of $e_n$ has a proper dense subspace as well.

There is no minimal dense subspace in an infinite-dimensional normed space.  An infinite-dimensional subspace always has a proper subspace that is dense in it.
Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional normed space. If $\varphi$ is an unbounded linear functional on $V$, then
$\varphi^\perp = \{x \in V : \; \varphi(x) = 0\}$ is a linear subspace that is dense in $V$.
Proof: Since $\varphi$ is unbounded, for every $n$ there is $v_n \in V$ with $\|v_n\| = 1$ and $|\varphi(v_n)| > n$.  For any $x \in V$ and any $n$, we can take
$u_n = x - \frac{\varphi(x)}{\varphi(v_n)} v_n \in \varphi^\perp$ with $\|x - u_n\| = \left|\varphi(x)/\varphi(v_n)\right| < |\varphi(x)|/n$.
An unbounded linear functional on $V$ can be obtained as follows: let $v_n$ be a linearly independent sequence in $V$. Define $\varphi$ on the linear span of the $v_n$ by
$\varphi(\sum_n c_n v_n) = \sum_n c_n n \|v_n\|$ (where only finitely many $c_n$ are nonzero). Then extend to the rest of $V$ using Zorn's Lemma.
